# How to insert ansible dictionary variable as yaml in template output file

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, ansible-template

I have this dictionary

```
env2:
  a: 20
  b: 50
  d: 90
```

Now i have this template file

```
name: "test"

env: "{{ env2 | to_nice_yaml(indent=8) }}"
```

When i run the playbook i get output as

```
env: "a: 20
b: 50
d: 90
"
```

how can i get output as

```
env:
  a: 20
  b: 50
  d: 90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Jinja filter [*indent*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.indent). For example, the template below

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml.j2
name: test

env:
  {{ env2|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    env2:
      a: 20
      b: 50
      d: 90

  tasks:

    - template:
        src: test.yml.j2
        dest: /tmp/test.yml
```

create the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.yml
name: test

env:
  a: 20
  b: 50
  d: 90
```